# Dynamic names for array variables and functions

Tags: javascript

I've recently been looking for dynamic variable names. And it worked well for me with `window["varName"+dynamic part]`

But is there any way to do it with arrays?

```
var monster2_data=[2,"Ugly Gremlin",20,"1-4"]
var monster3_data=[3,"Gremlin Mage",20,"3-7"]

function create_enemy(number){
document.getElementById("image").src="i/monstras"+number+".jpg";
document.getElementById("image").style.height="350px";
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute( "onClick", window["startbattle"+number+"();"] );
document.getElementById("name_of_monster").innerHTML="<span style=\"color:rgb(181,230,29);margin-left:-125px;\"> Level " +monster3_data[0]+": </span>"+monster3_data[1];
document.getElementById("monster_damage").innerHTML="Damage: "+monster3_data[3];
document.getElementById("monsterhp").max=monster3_data[2];
document.getElementById("monsterhp").value=monster3_data[2];
    }
```

As you see in this part of code, i need dynamic names for array variables. I've tried `window` also, but it returns `undefined`

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute( "onClick", window["startbattle"+number+"();"] );
```

this line particularly returns as: `onClick=undefined`

The part with `monster3_data[2];` works fine, but i need it to be like `monster(number)_data[2]`

So... my question would be: how to make dynamic names for functions and array vars?

Comment: window["varName"+dynamic part][index]

Comment: works with arrays, but doesnt work with function. Im trying: window["function_name"+dynamic]()

Comment: Why are you using `setAttribute` instead of `addEventListener` to add an event handler?

Comment: Or just document.getElementById("image").onclick=function() { ... }

Comment: Because it works fine for me @Barmar . and mplugjan i wouldnt like to use it because i have like 8 almost similar functions, where there are only some numbers changed, so it would take me too much of script for the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addEventListener` to add an event handler. The second argument is a function, not a function call, so you don't need parentheses after it.

```
document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", window["startbattle"+number]);
```

If you want to use the attribute it should be:

```
document.getElementById("image").onclick = window["startbattle"+number];
```

or:

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("onclick", "startbattle"+number+"();");
```

You don't need `window[...]` in the last case, because `setAttribute` converts its second argument to a string -- you can't put a function itself there. This is treated as Javascript to execute, and function names will be looked up in the global scope, so there's no need to specify `window`.

Comment: It somewhy doesnt add a correct number to the function. At the begining i have an image with attribute onclick="startbattle1()", so it remains startbattle1()

Comment: I didn't know you already had an event handler on the element. `addEventListener` doesn't replace the old handler, it just adds another one. I've updated the answer to show other ways of writing this that use the attribute, which replaces.

Answer (score 0):

"i need dynamic names for array variables." No you don't. It's nicer without them. I think so anyway. Instead of separate variables for each monster/level, make an object that contains both `monster2_data` and `monster3_data`. (That's sort of what you've done, except that you've chosen `window` as your object. You should avoid global variables wherever possible.) Also, `startbattle2` and `startbattle3` should be included in `monster2_data` and `monster3_data`.

```
var monster_data = {
    '2': [2,"Ugly Gremlin",20,"1-4",startbattle2],
    '3': [3,"Gremlin Mage",20,"3-7",startbattle3]
};

var do_battle;

function create_enemy(number){
    var monster = monster_data[number];
    do_battle = monster[4];
    document.getElementById("image").src="i/monstras"+number+".jpg";
    document.getElementById("image").style.height="350px";
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute( "onClick", "do_battle();" );
    document.getElementById("name_of_monster").innerHTML="<span style=\"color:rgb(181,230,29);margin-left:-125px;\"> Level " +monster[0]+": </span>"+monster[1];
    document.getElementById("monster_damage").innerHTML="Damage: "+monster[3];
    document.getElementById("monsterhp").max=monster[2];
    document.getElementById("monsterhp").value=monster[2];
}
```

Comment: I have two questions: does it impact loading speed or something or is it just better looking? And would do_battle work as function name or it will be treated as a new function?

Comment: Don't worry about speed, it's only 1 file and it's only a kilobyte or so. `do_battle` is fine: It's just a variable, and in javascript the value of a variable can be a function. First it looks at the `onclick` attribute, and finds that its value is `"do_battle();"`. Then it evaluates this as a javascript string in the global context. `do_battle` is a variable in the global scope, and its value is a function (eg `startbattle2`). So it calls the function. See http://jsfiddle.net/seyqz/ . Actually I'd prefer `addEventListener`, but I didn't want to rewrite too much.

Comment: Well i may even find some more cases where this would be more effective than what i use now. Anyway,  thank you for an option :)